# How to evaluate the derivative$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\sqrt{\frac{4+x²}{4-x²}}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I evaluate this derivative?:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\sqrt{\frac{4+x^2}{4-x^2}}\right)$$

Thank you.

Comment: $$\ln\sqrt{\frac{4+x²}{4-x²}} = \frac12 \ln(4+x^2) - \frac12 \ln(4-x^2) .$$

Comment: Use the chain rule repeatedly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'll exploit the properties of logarithms, recalling that $$\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^b =  b \ln\left(\frac ab\right) = b (\ln a - \ln b)$$

---

$$\begin{align} {\bf f(x)} & = \ln\sqrt{\frac{4+x^2}{4-x^2}} \\ \\ 
&= \ln\left(\frac{4+x^2}{4-x^2}\right)^{1/2}\\ \\
& = \frac 12\ln\left(\frac{4 + x^2}{4 - x^2}\right)\tag{$\ln\left(\frac ab\right)^c = c\ln\left(\frac ab\right)$}\\ \\
& = \frac12 \left(\ln(4+x^2) -  \ln(4-x^2)\right)\tag{$\ln\left(\frac ab\right) = \ln a - \ln b$}\\ \\
{\bf f'(x)} & = \frac 12\left( \frac{2x}{4 + x^2} + \frac{2x}{4 - x^2}\right)\tag{chain rule} \\ \\ & = \frac 12\left(\frac{2x[4-x^2 + 4 + x^2]}{16-x^4}\right) \\ \\ & = 
\frac{8x}{16 - x^4}\end{align}$$

---

Comment: Why, after the "not accepting enough answers" sermon, would you still chose to answer? Personally, I think someone is just posting his / her homework, week after week.

Comment: @nbubis The OP has accepted six out of sixteen answers. A bit low, by my lights, but acceptable (ahem).

Comment: @amWhy: Well, another TU from me ;-) +!

Comment: Thanks for helping! Actually I have little academic training even, and as I am at a public university, I have to seek the answers for myself, and sometimes I can not, therefore i do many questions of easy level. And also are not homework, are studies guided by myself that I want to understand. Sorry if I'm messing up, I would ask for a little more patience, and you are literally helping me to study and pass exams!

Comment: @user73276 No, you're not messing up! You're doing fine! Learning on one's own is a challenge. Glad to help. I'm a very patient person (and I realize math.se seems to be full of "rules" and "expectations" takes some getting accustomed to.)

Comment: Excellent job @amWhy +1! ;-)